# SQL to L2S Translation Help

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

So here is the original query

SELECT SUM(PickQty), SUM(ReqQty), AssignmentID, StopID
FROM PickRequest
GROUP BY AssignmentID, StopID

in LINQ

```
from a in dbReqs
group a by new { a.AssignmentID, a.StopID }
into pr
select new
{
Assignment = pr.Key,
StopID = pr.Select(s=> s.StopID),
PickQty = pr.Sum(p=> p.PickedQty),
Count = pr.Sum(c => c.ReqQty)
}
```

I must be doing something wrong because the LINQ version takes ages and the results seem a bit off.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
from a in dbReqs
group a by new { a.AssignmentID, a.StopID }
into pr
select new
{
  AssignmentID = pr.Key.AssignmentID,
  StopID = pr.Key.StopID,
  PickQty = pr.Sum(p=> p.PickedQty),
  Count = pr.Sum(c => c.ReqQty)
}
```

Note you can monitor what LINQ-to-SQL does quite easily:

```
ctx.Log = Console.Out; // or some other writer
```